# Return to Egypt: Allowed?

Tags: halacha, travel, egypt

There is an injunction on returning to Egypt. Why was it and is it ignored? For example, how is it that the Rambam an even Rabbi Ovadiah Yosef lived there?

Comment: ט  **מותר לחזור לארץ מצריים לסחורה ולפרקמטיה**, ולכבוש ארצות אחרות; ואין אסור אלא להשתקע שם.  ואין לוקין על לאו זה--שבעת הכניסה, מותר הוא; ואם יחשב לישב ולהשתקע, אין בו מעשה. He did it for parnassah

Comment: What do you mean `even Rabbi Ovadiah Yosef`? I strongly suspect he would be horrified by this characterisation.

Comment: Rabbi Ovadiah Yosef lived in Egypt? Also, keep in mind there is no prohibition in living in Egypt if you were born there.

Comment: Rabbi Ovadia Yosef was born in Iraq and lived in Egypt from 1947 to 1950 as head of the Cairo bet din.

Answer (score 15):

The [**Sefer Yereim**](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yereim.309.1) § 309 (303) answers that the ban only applies when leaving Eretz Yisroel for Mitzrayim.

The [**Ritva**](https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Yoma.38a.1) to **Yoma** 38a has another answer he says the ban only applies when most of the Jews live in Israel.

The **Rabbeinu Bechaye** says the ban on living in Mitzrayim only applied in the times of the Torah when the Egyptians were infamous for their immorality, latter it would not apply (especially seeing that they are Muslim)

The **Sho’el U’meishiv** by Rabbi Yosef Shaul Halevi Nathansohn says the ban only applies when the whole  of Klal Yisroel returns to Mitzrayim.

The **Divrei Shaul** (also by Rabbi Yosef Shaul Halevi Nathansohn) to **Numbers** 33:1,2 says it is only banned if we go back to Mitzrayim by the same route of 42 encampments that the Jews followed in the desert.

The **Semag** says since Sennacherib and the Assyrians sent away the original Egyptians the ban no longer applies.

Comment: Rambam left Eretz Yisrael for Mitzrayim: "Following this sojourn in Morocco, he and his family briefly lived in the Holy Land, before settling in Fostat, Egypt around 1168. " from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides

Comment: Can you provide sources for these opinions?

Comment: That doesn't help because the rambam himself doesnt hold of any of these, so you werent really meyashev the stira you just brought other peoples opinions.

Comment: Are these part of a sugya? Where can all these sources be found?

Answer (score 5):

For a start, consider what the Rambam says in Hilkhot Melakhim 5:8, to the effect that it is permissible to move there for financial reasons, etc, just not with the intention of settling. And that if one were to then decide to settle, he would not be lashed for this, since his moving there was permissible at the beginning. And if one were to change one's mind and decide not to leave, אין בו מעשה (this is not a "deed"; ie: it cannot be considered a transgression, since you have not actually done anything).

This opinion of his also helps us to understand what he says in halakha 9, to the effect that it is forbidden to leave the land of Israel. Before the Rambam settled in Egypt, he lived briefly in Acre, and made pilgrimage to Jerusalem. But as he says, this prohibition is only in effect at such a time as money is plentiful and life in the land of Israel is good. At all other times, it is permissible to leave in order to make a living.

The scriptural source for the aforementioned, which is alluded to in the following texts, is Deuteronomy 17:16 - "Only let him [the king] not multiply horses for himself, nor send the people back to Egypt in order to acquire horses, as the Lord has said to you: do not continue to return by this path any more".

To get to the essence of your question, so far as the Rambam in particular is concerned, note that this has been asked by others already. For example, R' Meir haKohen of Rothenburg (student of the Maharam; "Hagahot Maimoniot", 13th c.):

> ויש תימא על קהילות השוכנים שם, וגם רבינו המחבר עצמו הלך לגור שם, וליכא
> למימר שטעמו מפני שבא סנחריב ובלבל את העולם כדתניא בתוספתא דקידושין
> (פ"ה ה"ו) שאמר לו ר' עקיבא לבנינין גר המצרי, שהרי בפרק החליל אמרינן
> ואלכסנדריאה מ"ט איענוש משום דעברי אהאי קרא לא תוסיפו לשוב, וגם בתוספ'
> דמס' ידים (פ"ב ה"ח) אמרינן למצרים נתן הכתוב קצבה שנאמר (יחזקאל כט יג)
> מקץ ארבעים שנה אקבץ את מצרים מן העמים אשר נפוצו שם וישבו על אדמתם.
> ואין לנו טעם להתיר אם לא נפרש כפירוש רא"ם שפירש לא תוסיפו לא אסרה תורה
> אלא בדרך הזה כלומר מא"י למצרים אבל משאר ארצות מותר. ע"כ מסה"מ
>
> And one can wonder about the communities that do settle there - and even Rabbeinu the compiler himself went to live there - and it is
> not possible to say that his reason was that Sennacherib had mixed up
> the nations [and that therefore "Egypt" no longer exists in the same
> way that neither does Moab or Ammon, etc], as it says in the Tosefta
> for Kiddushin (5:6): "[Rabbi Yehuda said that Benjamin was an Egyptian
> convert and was the associate of one of R' Akiva's students. He said,
> "I am an Egyptian convert and I married an Egyptian convert. I am
> going to marry my son to the daughter of an Egyptian convert in order
> that my grandson will be able to enter the congregation, as it says
> (Deuteronomy 23:9): 'The third generation will enter the congregation
> of the Lord'".] Rabbi Akiva said to him, "Benjamin, [you have erred in
> the halakha. When Sennacherib came he confused all of the nations.
> Ammonites and Moabites are not in their place, Egyptians and Edomites
> are not in their place, but an Ammonite marries an Egyptian, an
> Egyptian marries an Ammonite - any of these can marry any of the
> families of the world, and any of the families of the world can marry
> any of these]".
>
> [It is not possible to say the foregoing in this
> instance] because in Perek HaChalil (Sukkah 51b) it says [about the
> community in] Alexandria [which was wiped out by Alexander the
> Macedonian], "What is the reason for their being punished? Because
> they transgressed, as the verse says (Deuteronomy 17:16): 'You shall
> not continue to return [by this path - ie: to Egypt]'". Also, in the
> Tosefta for Yadayim (2:8), it says: "Scripture has given a time for
> Egypt [by which they will be considered a nation again, despite the
> deeds of Sennacherib], as it says (Ezekiel 29:13): 'At the end of
> forty years I shall gather up Egypt from all of the nations where they
> are scattered and shall return them to their land'".
>
> [Given all of the
> above,] we would have no means of permitting [settlement in Egypt in
> the time of the Rambam] were it not for the explanation brought by the
> Re'em [probably R' Eliezer ben Shmuel of Metz, 12th c.), who
> explained: the Torah only forbade us from continuing via this path -
> which is to say, from the land of Israel to Egypt - but from all other
> nations it is permissible. See also [the Rambam's] Sefer haMitzvot
> (Negatives #227) [where he forbids selling land in the land of Israel
> in perpetuity].

Also, the following is brought by R' David ben Avi Zimra (Radbaz, 15th-16th c.):

> ויש ליתן טעם שלא אסרה תורה אלא לירד לגור שם ולהשתקע, כדאיתא בירושלמי
> לישיבה אי אתה חוזר אבל אתה חוזר לסחורה ולפרטמטיא ולכיבוש הארץ, וכל
> היורדים תחלה לא ירדו להשתקע אלא לסחורה ואע"ג דאחר כך נשתקעו אין כאן
> לאו אלא איסורא בעלמא ומפני טורח הטלטול ומיעוט הריוח במזונות בשאר
> המקומות לא חששו לאיסור זה וכן משמע מתחלת לשון רבינו שכתב אסור להתישב
> בה אלא שמסוף הלשון משמע דאיכא איסור לאו שכתב ואין לוקין על לאו זה וכו'
> משום שאין בו מעשה. ואפשר שהראשונים היו מפרשים כאשר כתבתי. ואם תאמר
> תקשי לרבינו שהרי נשתקע במצרים. ויש לומר דאנוס היה על פי המלכות שהיה
> רופא למלך והשרים. וגם אני נתישבתי שם זמן מרובה ללמוד תורה וללמדה
> וקבעתי שם ישיבה וכי האי גוונא מותר ושוב באתי לירושלים:
>
> And we can give as the reason that the Torah only forbade us to go down [to Egypt] to live there and to take root, as it says in the
> Yerushalmi: for settlement, you may not return, but you may return for
> business and for trade and for conquering the land. And all those who
> went down originally didn't do so to take root but for business, and
> even though they subsequently took root this was not a transgression
> but a general prohibition, and because of the effort of moving their
> possessions and the loss of income [incurred by going to] other
> places, they didn't worry about this prohibition. And this is
> understood from the beginning of Rabbeinu's formulation. He wrote, "It
> is forbidden to settle there", but at the end of his formulation it is
> understood not to be a transgressive prohibition since he writes that
> "we do not lash people for this transgression", etc, since "it is not
> a deed". And it is possible that the early generations interpreted it
> as I have written.
>
> And if you say that this contradicts Rabbeinu,
> since he took root in Egypt, one can say that he was forced by the
> government, since he was the physician to the king and his ministers.
> And I also once settled there for some time, to learn Torah and to
> teach it, and I established a yeshiva there - and in this way it is
> permissible - and then I returned to Jerusalem.

Apparently, as is brought in מקורות וציונים in the Fraenkel edition, R' Shmuel, one of the Rambam's grandsons, testified that the Rambam used to sign his letters with the words העובר בכל יום ג' לאוין ("who transgresses three prohibitions daily"). Assuming this to be true, this shows that he recognised that it was forbidden to dwell in Egypt, and perhaps supports the view of the Radbaz that he was forced to do so. See below, in the comments to this question, where @mevaqesh brings a variety of counter-arguments against the veracity of this claim, which may be historically spurious. In any case, if you read Joel L. Kraemer's excellent *Maimonides: The Life and World of One of Civilization's Greatest Minds* (New York: Doubleday, 2008), you'll see that he says the following on p.141:

> After leaving Hebron, Moses ben Maimon, with his father and brother,
> returned to Acre, remaining in that vicinity until May 1166, when they
> departed for Egypt. Egypt was the center of Mediterranean commerce
> with a large Jewish population. However, a rabbinic prohibition
> forbade dwelling in the land of Egypt, and we wonder how the Great
> Sage could flout a precept that he later codified as a law.
> Maimonides, so far as I know, did not try to justify his decision to
> settle in Egypt. His statement of the law contains a rationale. If
> someone came to Egypt to do business, he was not guilty when he
> entered. When he settled there, he did in fact transgress, but not in
> a way that deserved punishment.

Comment: That's beautifully comprehensive. Something that is not mentioned is why it's allowed to break a Torah law if it is for the sake of livelihood or work. That is probably another question altogether but here, it seems simply to be an assumption, or something taken on authority of tradition; I still don't understand it.

Comment: That would make for an interesting question in its own right, given that it's a proviso that doesn't exist for most other biblical rulings. My suspicion is that, in this instance, the ruling is mitigated by the fact that it speaks of returning to Egypt specifically "by that road", and even more specifically at the behest of a king (unlike, for example, Shabbat, which is more general in its application). But I don't know that for certain.

Comment: Mm, those thoughts make some sense. Shabbat also can be broken to save Jewish life/health, though. (Or is that why you mentioned it?)

Comment: I agree that the question really does stand in its own right.

Comment: First of all as already mentioned in the above comments the claim that Rambam signed his letters referencing his sin of living in Egypt is a spurious legend originating with R. Ishtori Haparchi of the 13-14th century.  THis is not found in any of the Rambam's letters.  Also the quote from the book "Maimonides" mistakenly refers to the prohibition as rabbinic when in reality it is Biblical (at least according to Maimonides).  THe answer to why business is okay is that the Yerushalmi infers that this is not "yeshiva" permanent prohibited residence.  THe author misunderstood Rambam's intent

Comment: In hilchos melachim as a confession of personal guilt rather than an illustration of why the sin carries no lashes.

Comment: Please edit the answer in light of my comments demonstrating the utter falsehood of some of the contents.

Comment: @mevaqesh, You haven't demonstrated anything, you've only asserted something. You have brought zero sources, just an opinion, so why should I align my answer with your POV? Write your own if you don't like it.

Comment: Please note that correcting the mistake in your answer wouldn't constitute an answer, so the there is no reason to raise the issue. Note also, that there is no malice whatsoever in my comments. In fact, I upvoted your answer (and many other posts of yours) in spite of containing mistakes that actually defame one of the greatest Jews. Regarding demonstration, I repeat that a) the legend stems centuries after his time.

Comment: b) the legend speaks of three prohibitions, a sure sign of a mistake, given that Rambam holds there is one; it is his disputant Bahag who holds three. c) the claim is that it is a rabbinical one; Rambam holds explicitly that is biblical SHM (neg. 36) d) the implication that his action was a sin and that the initial dwelling is a sin that simply wasn't deserving of punishment is the _opposite_ of what Rambam writes: מותר לחזור לארץ מצריים לסחורה ולפרקמטיה that if the justification is met, then it is _permissible_.

Comment: e) We have numerous letters from Rambam, including many penned by his own hand and he simply never ever writes this. | As a side-note, the author seems unaware that Rambam's admission that he sinned, in his "not rationale" is actually Rambam's reference to an explicit Yerushalmi.

Comment: @mevaqesh - For all I know, that may be true, but that still doesn't make what I wrote wrong. I prefaced it with "apparently" and provided two sources: the Rambam's grandson and Joel Kraemer. You want to disagree with them, go ahead, but you still haven't brought a source of your own. For all I know, this is your original research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51263/discussion-between-shimon-bm-and-mevaqesh).

Comment: Regarding the legend you cite, and my list of proofs that it is spurious, I contacted [R. Dr. Nahum Rabinovitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahum_Rabinovitch) who agreed that my proofs were compelling and that the legend is spurious. He pointed me to his יד פשוטה הלכות מלכים פרק ה הלכה ט, בפרט עמודים תקג-תקד. and הר״י שילת (ביאורו לאיגרות, עמ׳ רכט

Comment: Thanks, @mevaqesh - I have updated that paragraph and drawn the attention of readers to your comments. I am otherwise leaving it untouched since the Fraenkel edition does say this.

Comment: I am not sure why you are so devoted to reproducing mistakes just because someone else made them. AFAIK the Fraenkel edition is meant to be a compendium of works related to the MT. I doubt they would want a mistake's inclusion in their work to somehow legitimise it. BTW מבני בניו means a descendant; not a grandson. As I noted, Rambam had just two grandsons: R. David, and R. Ovadya. This R. Sh'muel is thought to be a 5th generation descendant.

Comment: Also, Rambam might have seen his move to Egypt as a sanctity of life. He fled to Egypt to escape impending danger from the Almohads in his native Spain and the Crusades in general.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=KplJAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP91&lpg=PP91&dq=%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A8+%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D+%D7%92%27+%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9F&source=bl&ots=NzmEzryQhA&sig=5WNgfb9CIJGk-QRc7mJQXBH-Y80&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP6bChg5rcAhWxiOAKHWMzCVYQ6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%92'%20%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9F&f=false

Comment: Only the Rambam would argue that moving there for financial reasons and then deciding to settle once there, would be qualitatively different than migrating there with the intent of settling to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

[The Rambam](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/metho67/18metho.htm) holds that it is prohibited (and put a post-script after his name as "someone who violates 3 commandments daily")

Comment: Any idea what the other two were supposed to have been?

Comment: I have heard (though I can't find the source right now) that this last part, about the Rambam's signature, is a myth. (msh210: the "3 commandments" refers to the three times that the Torah forbids us to return to Egypt.)

Comment: Found something about this, at http://www.halachayomit.co.il/DisplayRead.asp?readID=408 (based on the piskei halachah of R' Ovadiah Yosef):

ובאמת שמרן הרב שליט"א הביא כמה אחרונים שסירבו להאמין לשמועה זו, ומהם בספר שבילי דעת שכתב, וכמה יתחמץ לבבינו על עדות זו שכתב הכפתור ופרח, יען כי בידינו כמה איגרות של רבינו הרמב"ם ולא מצאנו חתימה זו כלל ועיקר. וכן העידו כמה חוקרים שראו כתבי יד של רבינו הרמב"ם, ולא נמצאה חתימה כזו כלל. וכן דחו שמועה זו רבים מן הפוסקים כי שמועת שוא היא.

Comment: @msh210, I heard once (unsubstantiated, though, and it seems that some now call into question whether the signature ever existed) that one of the sins was not living in E"Y.

Comment: @SethJ "Mekhilta on Parashat Beshalach announces: 'On three occasions the Torah warns against returning to Egypt." - http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/metho67/18metho.htm

Comment: and @msh210. It's possible that those three are three lavin on one act

Comment: @mevaqesh, a factually incorrect answer that relies on sources you find unreliable or wrong is a good reason to downvote. It is not a reason to delete an answer.