# Kashrut: Meat and dairy

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, meat-and-milk, dairy

My family owns a farm that produces fresh food, including dairy and meat. Would the prohibition to eat milk and meat together still apply since I have ascertained that the cow from which milk was obtained is not the mother of the cow slaughtered for meat? Thanks.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14379/basic-laws-why-is-milk-with-meat-not-kosher

Comment: @MalkaS Yes. And if you have a farm, I recommend making friends with an Orthodox rabbi, since there are a lot of difficult halachos involved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although the Torah says not to cook "in the milk of the mother", this is a common example, since the mother's milk is at hand. In actuality any meat is forbidden with any milk. (Tur Yore De'a 87, [Shulchan Aruch YD 87:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=386))