# How many Pesukim in the Tora warn against Idolatry?

Tags: number, avodah-zarah, pentateuch-chumash

A fellow teacher wishes to present to their class the severity of Idol Worship.  They thought it may be impactful if they presented to the class how many Pesukim warn against Idol Worship.  Perhaps someone here may know.

How many verses in the Torah warn against Idolatry?

Do any Mefarshim use this to demonstrate the severity of Idol Worship according to the Torah?

Comment: This question would be more compelling if you'd [edit] in why you want to know this fact.

Comment: According to the Baal HaTurim, 48. See here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8662/603

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which mitzvah is repeated the most times in the Chumash?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8558/which-mitzvah-is-repeated-the-most-times-in-the-chumash) While the question is different, the answer gives the answer to this question.