# Is there a prohibition against living in Egypt?

Tags: mitzvah, egypt

On a different website, in response to a question from a gentile about how it was possible to keep all 336 [sic] commandments, one commenter said that he found not living in Egypt and not cutting down fruit-bearing trees the easiest to follow.

I was aware of issues around cutting down fruit-bearing trees, but not of any prohibition against living in Egypt. Such a statement seemed especially odd to me seeing as there has been a significant Jewish presence in Egypt from Ancient times all the way until the modern day (although since the foundation of the modern State of Israel this population has pretty much entirely made aliyah or died out), and the presence of famous scholars like the Rambam in Egypt.

Does any such prohibition exist?

Comment: 336 commandments? It may help to link the website you are talking about, for context.

Comment: Possibly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2637/27180

Comment: @Shmuel the 336 was as the asker said. They meant 613 mitzvot, but made an error. It was a private facebook group

Comment: additional related question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2636/return-to-egypt-allowed

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ritva on Yoma 38a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Yoma.38a?vhe=Chiddushei_HaRitva,_Berlin,_1860.&lang=en) writes that the prohibition to live in Egypt (Mitzrayim) no longer applies:

> אלכסנדריא של מצרים. פי׳ דאע״ג דכתי׳ לא תוסיפון לשוב בדרך הזה עוד כבר פירשו בסיפרי לגור שם אי אתה חוזר אבל אתה חוזר לסחורה ולכבוש את הארץ. ומיהו תמיהא מלתא על מה סמכו העולם לגור בזמן הזה במצרים כגון הרמב״ם ז״ל וכמה גדולים אחרים. ויש אומרים שאותן עיירות כבר נתבלבלו ונחרבו ואלו עיירות אחרות הן שנתיישבו אחרי כן וה״ר אליעזר ממיץ תירץ שלא אסר הכתוב אלא להולך בדרך ההוא שמארץ ישראל והמדבר למצרים דהכי כתיב קרא לא תוסיפון לשוב בדרך הזה. והנכון יותר שאין האיסור ההוא אלא בזמן שישראל שרויין על אדמתם אבל בזמן הזה שנגזר עלינו להיות נדחים בכל קצוי הארץ כל חוצה לארץ אחד הוא ואין איסור אלא שלא לצאת מדעת מן הארץ לחוצה לארץ.
> 2
> (no time for translation at this moment)

The [Ramban on Shemos 14:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.14.13.1?ven=Commentary_on_the_Torah_by_Ramban_(Nachmanides)._Translated_and_annotated_by_Charles_B._Chavel._New_York,_Shilo_Pub._House,_1971-1976&vhe=On_Your_Way_New&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes however, that this prohibition is for every generation:

> FOR WHEREAS YE HAVE SEEN THE EGYPTIANS TODAY, YE SHALL SEE THEM AGAIN NO MORE. In the opinion of our Rabbis, this is a negative commandment for all times.

Similary, one of the places where it says that the prohibition still applies, can be found in the [Sefer HaChinukh, on mitzvah 500](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.500.1?ven=Sefer_HaChinukh,_translated_by_R._Francis_Nataf,_Sefaria_2018&vhe=Sefer_HaChinukh_--_Torat_Emet&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> To not ever dwell in the Land of Egypt: That we not further go back on the way to Egypt ever; meaning to say that we do not establish our residence in Egypt. And about this is it stated (Deuteronomy 17:16), "and the Lord said to you, 'You shall not further go back on this way again.'" And the prevention of this is repeated three times: They, may their memory be blessed, said (Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 14:13:2), "In three places did the Torah warn not to return to the Land of Egypt [...] In the three they returned, and in the three they were punished." And these three places [are] the one we mentioned; the second is "by the way that I said to you, 'You shall not further again, etc.'" (Deuteronomy 28:68); and the third is "as that which you see Egypt today, you shall not further, etc." (Exodus 14:13) - and even though it appears to be [only] a story from its revealed meaning, the tradition comes about it that it is a prevention (a negative commandment).

[And](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.500.4?ven=Sefer_HaChinukh,_translated_by_R._Francis_Nataf,_Sefaria_2018&vhe=Sefer_HaChinukh_--_Torat_Emet&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> And this prohibition is practiced in every place and at all times by males and females. And one who transgresses it and establishes his residence there violates this negative commandment. But we do not administer lashes for this negative commandment, since no act is [involved] with it. As at the time of the entry, it is permitted, and there is no act in his lingering there. And Rambam, may his memory be blessed, said (Mishneh Torah, Laws of Kings and Wars 5:8) that if a king of Israel conquers the Land of Egypt according to the word of the court, it would be permissible for us to dwell in it. And 'the words of the wise are grace.'

The Rambam, cited by the Sefer HaChinukh, writes in his [Mishneh Torah (Kings and Wars, chapter 5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.5.8?ven=Laws_of_Kings_and_Wars._trans._Reuven_Brauner,_2012&vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that the prohibition only applies to "permanently residing":

> It is permissible to return to Egypt to conduct business and commerce or to conquer other lands. The prohibition is only against residing permanently there.

Furthermore, the Rambam states:

> It appears to me that if an Israelite king conquers Egypt with the permission of the Court, it would be permitted to live there. The warning against returning was said for individuals or to live there when (Egypt) is in the hands of the non-Jews since their deeds are more corrupt than all the other nations, as it says, “as the doings of the Land of Egypt” (Levit. 18:3).

See also the opinion of the [Semag (Sefer Mitzvot Gadol) (Levush 227)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Mitzvot_Gadol%2C_Negative_Commandments.227.1?vhe=Munkatch,_1901&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94%20(%D7%90)%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%22%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%90%27%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%20%D7%91%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A%20%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%2C%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%99%27%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%20%5B%D7%91%D7%A1%22%D7%A4%20%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%99%5D%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%94%20%D7%97%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%94%20%D7%97%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%20(%D7%91)%20%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%9D%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90%20%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%27%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%27%20%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F%20%5B%D7%A4%22%D7%94%5D%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%20%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%92%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%95%27%2C%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A1%27%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%90%20%5B%D7%A4%22%D7%91%5D%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%20%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%90%27%20%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A5%20%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%A5%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9D%2C%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%9E%22%D7%98%20%D7%93%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%94%D7%90%D7%99%20%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%95%27%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F%20(%D7%92)%20%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%20%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91%20%D7%A8%22%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A5%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%92%D7%95%27%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A%20%D7%94%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%27%20%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8%3A&with=Lexicon&lang2=en):

> צוה (א) הקב"ה שלא ישובו ישראל למצרים שנא' לא תוסיפו לשוב בדרך הזה עוד, וגרסי' בירושלמי [בס"פ חלק ובאלפסי] לישיבה אי אתה חוזר אבל אתה חוזר לסחורה ולפרגמטיא ולכבוש הארץ ויש (ב) תימה על כמה קהילות השוכנים שם וגם רבינו משה בר מיימון הלך לשם לגור ושמא טעמו משום שעלה סנחרב ובילבל כל העולם כולו וגם מצרים נתבלבלו כדתני' בתוס' דקידושין [פ"ה] אמר לו רבי עקיבא למנימין גר המצרי טעית כבר עלה סנחריב וכו', אמנם מצינו רבי יהושע שנחלק עליו במס' ידים בתוספתא [פ"ב] ואומר שם למצרים נתן להם הכתוב קצבה שנא' מקץ ארבעים שנה אקבץ מצרים מן העמים אשר נפוצו שם וישובו על אדמתם, וגם בסוכה אומר ואלכסנדריא מ"ט דאיענוש משום דעברו אהאי קרא דלא תוסיפו לשוב וגו' ואותו מעשה היה אחר בלבול של סנחריב ואין (ג) טעם להתיר אם לא נפרש כפירוש הרב ר"א ממיץ לא תוסיפו וגו' לא אסרה תורה אלא בדרך הזה כלו' מארץ ישראל למצרים אבל משאר ארצות מותר: